# Registration of address in Portugal

Tags: residency, portugal

I've recently moved to Portugal, and I'm not sure the requirements for registering your address. I'm aware that in some EU countries (Germany, for example) you have to register fairly quickly. Whereas in the UK (where I'm from), you basically have to register with the local council for electoral and council tax, but the timescale is basically a little bit more flexible.

I haven't rented anywhere, but I do have a permanent address, so nobody (e.g. letting agent) has provided any "to do list" around this. Can anyone provide any guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UK's very own Foreign Office actually provides [a guide that should be useful to you](https://www.gov.uk/living-in-portugal). It includes this:

> If you intend to remain in Portugal for more than 3 months, you must apply for a registration certificate from the Town Hall (Câmara Municipal) in your area of residence. This has to be done within 4 months of arrival in Portugal. […] For entitlement to local services - ie schools, healthcare, and social security - people living in Portugal must register with the Portuguese authorities.

The [EU also provides similar information](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/registering-residence/portugal/index_en.htm). This *Certificado de Registo* is not a general registration system like there is in Germany but rather a residence card for EU citizens. It costs EUR 15 and there is a pretty heavy fine (EUR 500-2500) if you fail to register.

Further information in Portuguese: [FAQ from the Immigration and Borders Service](http://www.sef.pt/portal/v10/PT/aspx/apoioCliente/detalheApoio.aspx?fromIndex=1&id_Linha=4641) and [the government's “citizens' portal”](http://www.portaldocidadao.pt/PORTAL/entidades/MAI/SEF/pt/SER_certificado+de+registo+para+cidadao+da+ue+eee+suica.htm).

Comment: Fantastic! That's exactly what I was looking for! I've been looking for this for weeks and not found it - I think my Google muscles are rusting!